# Dynamic parenting in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, parent

I am trying to set up dynamic parenting of some vertices to an empty based on their distance from the empty in Animation Nodes, to be able to move these vertices with this empty.

I am ok with selecting the vertices but I am running into problems after using **Object Attribute Output** with a `parent` as the attribute with a value of the empty object.

[image]
What happens is that the vertices are being pushed away from their places by the vector equal to their distance from the world origin.

In the simplest situation, I would just use the **Object ID key** for initial transforms and use matrix math to calculate the location based on the empty, however, the aim is to be able to use different empties one after another to control the vertices, for that my initial transforms saved in the **Object ID key** will be irrelevant.

So my question is, is there any trick to properly set up parenting in AN? Just to say, if I manually parent the vertices with the empty, they behave as intended.

Comment: Maybe using the actual blender operator in a script would let you use the operator `parent_no_inverse_set` or whatever it is called for vertices ? Could you post the relevant part of your node network ?

Comment: Thank you @Gorgious. I added the network. It is really simple. I was thinking about scripting but thought that maybe it would be possible with just nodes.

Comment: OK. I used Python and `vert.parent = rotator; 
vert.matrix_parent_inverse = rotator.matrix_world.inverted()` to avoid the vertices changing the position upon parenting but now when I rotate the empty (rotator here) the parented vertices do not move.

Comment: Actually it does work, just needed to change a node tree a bit.